# How to autoscale a rabbitmq container in ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, rabbitmq, amazon-ecs

In a container based micro service application, How to autoscale rabbitmq container in ECS?

Do I have to scale it up with dynamic ports and assign to a load balancer?

Comment: Have you read [the fine manual](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ec2.html) and followed the links?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: documentation doesn't provide information for docker. it has only standalone linux setup

Comment: i need a solution to work with ECS.